# ImportError: cannot import name 'enums'

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I am trying to use Google Speech API to recognize speech from mic input in real time. I have tried `https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/cloud-client/transcribe_streaming_mic.py`
 but this error came out. Anybody knows how to solve this?

```
from google.cloud.speech import enums
ImportError: cannot import name 'enums'
```

**Update:**
I have solved the problem by running the code in virtual environment as suggested by the official Cloud Speech API website. However, I still dont understand why we need to run that in virtual environment instead of my original environment as the virtual environment is not Linux or other OS.

Comment: Seems a dumb question but did you install google-cloud-speech first?

Comment: yes, I installed it.

Comment: I have tried and it works on both virtualenv and normal. Did you accidentally install with say python3 and are running with another python? (maybe you have dual installed.) @sttc1998

Answer (score 0):

I am using cloud function to transcribe the audio to text.
I believe the documentation for google-cloud-speech has been updated, you may refer to the documentation. https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-speech/. I believe the class is now called speech_v1, you can use the alias "as speech" to make the github sample codes work.

```
from google.cloud import speech_v1 as speech
from google.cloud.speech_v1 import enums
from google.cloud.speech_v1 import types
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I got mine working with the following import

```
from google.cloud.speech_v1.gapic import enums
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `pip install google.cloud.speech`, you are getting the latest version, currently **V2**.

In **V2**, *enums* and *types* have been removed and are no longer needed.

[https://github.com/googleapis/python-speech/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#enums-and-types](http://By%20using%20pip%20install%20google.cloud.speech,%20you%20are%20getting%20the%20latest%20version,%20currently%20V2.%20%20In%20V2,%20enums%20and%20types%20have%20been%20removed%20and%20are%20no%20longer%20needed.%20%20https://github.com/googleapis/python-speech/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#enums-and-types)