# Google Cloud Natural Language Import Error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-language

I am having a lot of trouble with getting the Google Cloud Natural Language API running. I am trying to run a Python program in Linux on a Google VM. I am also unsure of how to run a full Traceback of the error. The following code is not working:

`from google.cloud import language
from google.cloud.language import enums
from google.cloud.language import types`.

On Python 2 I get the error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "natlangex.py", line 3, in <module>
    from google.cloud.language import enums
ImportError: cannot import name enums`

I tried upgrading to Python 3 and when I run Python 3 I get the error:
And I updated to Python 3. One thing that is confusing is that when I run Python 3 the error is a bit different:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "natlangex.py", line 2, in <module>
    from google.cloud import language
ImportError: No module named 'google'`

Here are the other things I have tried:

- I installed the SDK.
- I set `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="apikey.json"`.
- I tried `!pip install google-cloud-language`
- I upgraded pip `pip install --upgrade setuptools pip.`

I am very lost! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try this `->` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53511406/importerror-cannot-import-name-enums

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using wrong syntax because of the library update, you may refer now to the new one, following [1] and more specifically [2].

It seems that the official Natural Language documentation of Google Cloud is not updated yet [3], but at the end of this documentation you have links to the Python Client Library [1][2] where it explains the changes.

Your imports should be:

```
from google.cloud import language_v1
from google.cloud.language_v1 import enums
from google.cloud.language_v1 import types
```

[1] https://googleapis.dev/python/language/latest/api.html

[2] https://googleapis.dev/python/language/latest/gapic/v1/api.html

[3] https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python